# Returning statement

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a problem that I can't fix by myself. In my `getAlldata()` method I need to return all the data from my collection `kljenti`. I don't know what kind of data type I need to use in my method declaration and return statement.
I have tried a lot of solutions but they didn't work.

```
  public void getAllData () {
        try {
            var connectionString = "mongodb://172.16.1.24:27017";
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var server = client.GetServer();
            var database = server.GetDatabase("kljenti");
            var Client = new MongoClient();
            var DB = Client.GetDatabase("knjigoMata");
            var kolekcija = DB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("kljenti");
            var allDocuments = kolekcija.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();

            foreach (var kljenti in allDocuments) {
                Console.WriteLine(kljenti);
            }

            return allDocuments;

        } catch {
            MessageBox.Show("Nemogu prikazati podatke o korisnicima");
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have a error in this line :                 List <string> allDocuments = kolekcija.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: cannot covert type BsonDocument to List ,implicity...

Comment: Because [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a single item. What is `Find(new BsonDocument())` supposed to find, anyway? You're not giving it any values for the predicate. Maybe you just want `kolekcija.ToListAsync();`?

Comment: find method is mongodb driver method

Comment: my mistake, I didn't see that tag.

Comment: i don't know how to fix that problem, i am in that problem almost 2 days :(

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend deserializing the klijenti table into a c# object.
1. Create a class that represents the klijenti table. For example:

```
public class Klijent
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

2. Then use

```
List<Klijent> res = db.FindAs<Klijent>.ToList();
```

3. List is the return type as you requested.

Comment: mongo does not contain a method FindAs()

Comment: http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.8.3/html/49accca1-8e23-8942-488e-2eabbfefed12.htm

Comment: i'm using another driver , mongo driver 2.0.2 c#

Comment: It should be there according to the documentation: http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/Methods_T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollection_1.htm

Answer (score 0):

ToListAsync() returns `Task<List<BsonDocument>>` in this case.  So to make this work, you have to wait for the task to complete, then return the task Result.

For example:

```
public List<BsonDocument> getAllData()
{
    try
    {
        var connectionString = "mongodb://172.16.1.24:27017";
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var database = server.GetDatabase("kljenti");
        var Client = new MongoClient();
        var DB = Client.GetDatabase("knjigoMata");
        var kolekcija = DB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("kljenti");
        Task<List<BsonDocument>> task = kolekcija.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();

        task.Wait();
        List<BsonDocument> allDocuments = task.Result;
        foreach (var kljenti in allDocuments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(kljenti);
        }
        return allDocuments;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nemogu prikazati podatke o korisnicima");
    }
}
```